# Rolling initiative for a group of tokens in Roll20?

Tags: tools, roll20

Is there a way to select a group of generic tokens in Roll20, have them roll initiative, and have these values added to the turn tracker? The following command does it for one selected token:

```
[[1d20 + ?{Modifier|0} &{tracker}]]
```

--given that the tokens are generic, the command asks for a (Dex) modifier. Is there a way to extend this command to a group?

Comment: Is this a [dnd-5e] specific question, or does it apply to any game that uses an initiative roll?

Comment: Fixed, sorry--habit and all that jazz :).

Comment: I've always handled this for groups of identical minions by just adding one of them to the turn tracker and moving them as a group :D

Comment: @gatherer818 works well, until you kill the one you added (oops that was my total rookie mistake last week)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to be a Mentor to do this: you can find the relevant script discussed [here](https://app.roll20.net/forum/post/207066/script-auto-initiative/#post-568537) and available for download [here](https://gist.github.com/DarokinB/5826648) (or at the top of the discussion, in the previous link).

The discussion in the first link includes tips and comments for adapting the script to other systems.

Comment: Would be helpful for a summary or highlight of the script in question.

Comment: @waxeagle: True; done.

Answer (score 7):

The &{tracker} syntax to automatically roll a token into the turn tracker **does not work** for multiple selected tokens. As you've discovered, only one of the selected tokens will be added.

Your only options are to roll each token separately (which shouldn't take too long if you've got a macro set up), or use the API, which can easily add multiple objects to the turn tracker at once (including rolling their initiative). Unfortunately, the API requires that the campaign owner has a Mentor subscription.

Comment: Of course, you can always make a thread in the the Roll20 suggestion forums to add the group rolling functionality. I doubt you'd get much disagreement from other users! ;)

Comment: Just did, hope I garners some support!